# How to link both Google and Apple providers in Firebase auth Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, google-signin, apple-sign-in

Yesterday I added Apple sign in (using sign_in_with_apple package) and after successful login with AppleID (using iPad Simulator iOS 16.2) in Firebase console my user shown both providers (I'm using a gmail address for AppleID).
My Firebase Authentication settings is set to `Link accounts that use the same email`.

As a test I then deleted my user account from Firebase console to try and see what was returned from Apple when user chooses to hide the email and as no email is returned firebase auth throws the `invalid-email` error.
Today I changed the firebase_auth version from `4.2.4` to `4.2.10` as it was just released but even changing it back doesn't give me the the same behaviour I had yesterday (two providers for same account). Actually for a while `currentUser` wasn't even getting the user info from Google Provider and I had to implement a little added code to get user details from `userInfo` and update currentUser manually..( see commented portion in google sign in method), then it stated working as expected again.

So I have two possible auth scenarios which I need to manage.

1st:

- I login with Apple, it succeeds.
- The account in firebase console shows the apple Provider.
- I then logout and login with Google.
- Now the account shows only the Google provider, not both as it was at my first login with Apple yesterday.
- Then if I logout and login with Apple again the login fails as Apple authorises the AppleId just once.

What should I do in this case, store somewhere the authorised AppleID credentials gotten from `SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential()` for future logins?

2nd:

- I start logging in with Google and it succeeds.
- The account in firebase console shows the Google Provider.
- I then logout and when I try to login with Apple I get `[firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account` error, which I hadn't have yesterday at my first attempt.

As `await _firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(userEmail);` shows that `google.com` is one of the entries of the array and as `linkWithCredentials()` is only available from the `currentUser` I added a check and if any other provider is found ( google in this case ) I call the `signInWithGoogle()` method to make the user sign with google first and then I could link the Apple credentials but it throws `'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/providers/google_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 43 pos 12: 'accessToken != null || idToken != null': At least one of ID token and access token is required` error, which I don't understand why as it's the method called from the Google login button.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?
All always many thanks for your help, and sorry for the long question, but I tried to describe the weird situation I have since a couple of days.

Cheers.

## Google sign in

```
Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    print('signInWithGoogle() started');
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser =
        await _googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((e) {
      print('Google sign in error: $e');
    });

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
        await googleUser?.authentication;

    final AuthCredential? credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken);

    UserCredential userCredentials =
        await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential!);
    User? firebaseUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    print('UserRepository.signInWithGoogle() logged in user is $firebaseUser');

    /// currentUser now displays correct info again from Auth Provider.
    // UserInfo userInfo;
    // if (firebaseUser != null) {
    //   for (int i = 0; i < userCredentials.user!.providerData.length; i++) {
    //     userInfo = userCredentials.user!.providerData[i];
    //     if (userInfo.providerId == 'google.com') {
    //       print(
    //           'UserRepository.signInWithGoogle() updating user displayName as: ${userInfo.displayName} and photoUrl as: ${userInfo.photoURL} ');
    //       await firebaseUser.updateDisplayName(userInfo.displayName);
    //       // await firebaseUser.updateEmail(userInfo.email!);
    //       await firebaseUser.updatePhotoURL(userInfo.photoURL);
    //       await firebaseUser.reload();
    //       print(
    //           'UserRepository.signInWithGoogle() user with updated displayName and photoUrl is $firebaseUser');
    //     }
    //   }
    // }

    return firebaseUser;
  }
```

## Apple sign in

```
Future<User?> signInWithApple() async {
    User? firebaseUser;

    /// To prevent replay attacks with the credential returned from Apple, we
    /// include a nonce in the credential request. When signing in in with
    /// Firebase, the nonce in the id token returned by Apple, is expected to
    /// match the sha256 hash of `rawNonce`.
    final rawNonce = generateNonce();
    final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

    /// Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
    final AuthorizationCredentialAppleID appleIdCredential =
        await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
      nonce: nonce,
    ).catchError((e) {
      print(
          'UserRepository.signInWithApple() SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential error: $e');
    });
    print(
        'UserRepository.signInWithApple() SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential is $appleIdCredential');
    // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.

    final OAuthProvider appleProvider = OAuthProvider("apple.com");
    final oauthCredential = appleProvider.credential(
      idToken: appleIdCredential.identityToken,
      rawNonce: rawNonce,
    );

    final displayName =
        '${appleIdCredential.givenName} ${appleIdCredential.familyName}';
    final userEmail = '${appleIdCredential.email}';

    /// OK
    print(
        'UserRepository.signInWithApple() user from apple credential is: $displayName, $userEmail');

    final signInMethods =
        await _firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(userEmail);
    print(
        'UserRepository.signInWithApple() user signInMethods are: $signInMethods');

    /// sign in or link credentials
    if (signInMethods.contains('google.com')) {
      print(
          'UserRepository.signInWithApple() user already have Google credentials');
      _googleSignIn.signOut();
      firebaseUser = await signInWithGoogle().catchError((e) {
        print(
            'UserRepository.signInWithApple() signInWithGoogle() call error: $e');
      });

      print('UserRepository.signInWithApple() linking Apple credentials');
      await firebaseUser?.linkWithCredential(oauthCredential).catchError((e) {
        print(
            'UserRepository.signInWithApple() linking Apple credentials error: $e');
      });
    } else {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential).catchError((e) {
        print('_firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential) error: $e');
        throw e;
      });
      ;
    }

    /// sign in
    // await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential).catchError((e) {
    //   print('_firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential) error: $e');
    //   throw e;
    // });
    firebaseUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    await firebaseUser?.updateDisplayName(displayName);
    await firebaseUser?.updateEmail(userEmail);
    await firebaseUser?.reload();

    /// not updated
    print(
        'UserRepository.signInWithApple() updated firebaseUser is $firebaseUser');

    var currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

    ///correct
    print(
        'UserRepository.signInWithApple() user from firebaseAuth.currentUser is:$currentUser');
    return firebaseUser;
  }
```